# Override DataAnnotations to pull from Resx file by default

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, internationalization, resources, resx

I am trying to add some localization to an ASP>NET MVC 4 project. I have been successful in doing this, but.....

This I do not like -

```
  [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredField")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredField")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]        
    public string Suffix { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredField")]
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
```

What I want is a way to automatically set a Default resource file for all of my Data Annotations and the key default to the NAme of the property.

What I am thinking would work: Is there a way to override the built in Data annotations, for Example [Required], and set it to use my "Resources.Resources" by Default and use the Name for the key to search in the resource file? Also if the key doesn't exist default it to something. Right now if a key doesn't exists it breaks the site.

Essentially I was asked if there is a better way to do this as opposed to copying and pasting this "[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredField")]" sort of thing everywhere.

Let me know if I need to clarify.